# Scilab - Populating 100 matrices from excel

Tags: matrix, scilab

I need to multiply three matrices (X, Y and Z) together in Scilab. I have 100 versions of matrix Z to populate with data from an excel file and I need to multiply XYZ for each version, I am fine doing it for one matrix but I cannot get the process to repeat 100 times. Matrix Z has 7 columns so at the moment my code looks something like this:

```
Trial = read_csv("Testrun2.csv")
index = 0
while index<100

  Z=[msprintf(Trial(1+(index*7),2)) msprintf(Trial(2+(index*7),2))...

  Test = Z.*Y.*X
  disp(index);
  index = index + 1;
end
```

I have looked online but can find nothing that works, any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Dan

Answer (score 1):

If you use `msprintf` that will produce a string which can not be multiplied with a number: `"2"*2` will give an error. To convert a string to a number you can use `strtod` and I think its better to do in the beginnig e.g.

```
T=strtod(Trial);
```

After that you can index `T` in a usual way, e.g.

```
Z=T(1:3,1:3);
```

Another possible solutions:
1.) `read_csv` have a string matrix output by default, but you can change it to double if you want (see help for `read_csv`).
2.) If you use `csvRead` its default mode is double, see https://help.scilab.org/docs/5.5.1/en_US/read_csv.html